# AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed randomly to write the video

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I am creating the video from a set of images with AVAssetwriter and AVAssetExportSession and successfully getting the video and save it to the documents. But randomly the video exporting failed and it shows An Unknown error occured with error code -11800.

```
   ExportSessionError: -11800 adn userinfo{
   NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation could not be completed";
   NSLocalizedFailureReason = "An unknown error occurred (-12124)";
   NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12124 \"The operation   couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -12124.)\"";
```

This is the error console i got.. Please help me.. Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code here. I have done the same thing, but works perfectly for me.

Comment: @hemkaran_raghav Here i post the code.. Pls check it.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681429/avasserexportsession-failed-randomly)